# Doctrine2: Doctrine query returns different results from raw query?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have come across this multiple times in the past, and I just ended up writing a raw SQL query to overcome it, but I really want to find out why this is happening. Look at the statement below

```
$q = $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT um,s,st
                    FROM Dashboard\Entity\Metric um
                    JOIN um.stat st
                    JOIN um.site s
                    JOIN s.clients c
                    WHERE c.id = ?1
                    AND s.competitor = 0
                    AND s.ignored = 0
                    AND st.id IN (?2)
                    GROUP BY s.id, st.id
                    ORDER BY st.response_field, s.id')
                    ->setParameter(1, $params['c_id'])
                    ->setParameter(2, $statId);

        $sql = $q->getSql();
        $rs = $q->getResult();
```

If I take the contents of `$sql` and paste them into a mySQL tool and run the raw query, it returns 18 results which is correct.

However, `$rs` only contains 3 results. `$statId` is a comma-separated string of 6 numbers: (1,2,3,4,5,6). So I am grouping by `st.id`, and `s.id`. There will be 3 `s.id` elements for every `st.id` element, working out to the 18 results I expected. What's happening is Doctrine is only returning the first `st.id` which is the group of 3 `s.id` 's

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from IRC, but posting here in case it helps someone else. Smart WHERE IN statements aren't planned for support until 2.1 version.

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-dev/browse_thread/thread/fbf70837293676fb

But I can accomplish the same goal with query builder.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html